# tree sorting in groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

Giving a LinkedHashMap, i' m trying fo build a full xml tree in groovy.

1) the map:

```
def trees = [:]
trees.put(1,[id:'1',path:'ROOT/folder1',name:'folder1',isFolder:'true'])
trees.put(2,[id:'2',path:'ROOT/folder1/folder1.1',name:'folder1.1',isFolder:'true'])
trees.put(3,[id:'3',path:'ROOT/folder1/folder1.1/folder1.1.1',name:'folder1.1.1',isFolder:'true'])
trees.put(4,[id:'4',path:'ROOT/folder2',name:'folder2',isFolder:'true'])
trees.put(5,[id:'5',path:'ROOT/folder3',name:'folder3',isFolder:'true'])
trees.put(6,[id:'6',path:'ROOT/folder3/folder3.1',name:'folder3.1',isFolder:'true'])
```

2) Sort Tree closure:

```
//def rslt = { [:].withDefault{ owner.call() } }
def a = []
def rslt = { [:].withDefault{ owner.call() } }().with { t ->
  trees.each { k, v ->
    v.path.tokenize( '/' ).inject( t ) { tr, i -> tr[ i ] }
  }
  return t
}
```

3) how to build an  Xml doc, with xml slurper for instance,

a model would be like this:

```
<ROOT>
<folder1 name="folder1" id="1" parent="ROOT" depth="1" path="ROOT/folder1">
      <folder1.1 name="folder1.1" id="2" parent="folder1" depth="2" path="ROOT/folder1/folder1.1">
           <folder1.1.1 name="folder1.1.1" id="3" parent="folder1.1" depth="3" path="ROOT/folder1.1/folder1.1.1"/>
       </folder1.1>
</folder1>
...
</ROOT>
```

looking for a closure using sthg like  groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw).with {

Any idea or suggestions ?

BR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your XML with `groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder` by walking recursively through the node map. The map you create in your second step loses all the attributes defined in `trees` though. To keep them you will have to change that part first:

```
// An empty map. Default value for nonexistent elements is an empty map.
def struc = {[:].withDefault{owner.call()}}()

trees.each { key, val ->
    // iterate through the tokenized path and create missing elements along the way
    def substruc = struc
    val.path.tokenize('/').each {
        // if substruc.nodes does not exist it will be created as an empty map
        // if substruc.nodes[it] does not exist it will be created as an empty map
        substruc = substruc.nodes[it]
    }
    // assign the attributes to the map in .attr
    val.each{ attrKey, attrVal ->
        substruc.attr[attrKey] = attrVal
    }
}
```

This will result in a map like this:

```
[nodes: [ROOT: [nodes: [folder1: [attr: [id:1, ...], nodes: [...]]]]]
```

The closure that will be used in the `StreamingMarkupBuilder` will use another closure to iterate through the nodes in `struc` recursively while assigning `.attr` as the node's attributes and `.nodes` as the node's child nodes.

```
// we will use this builder to create our XML
def builder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
builder.encoding = "UTF-8"

// closure for our xml structure
def xml = {
    // closure to be recursively called for each element in the nodes maps
    def xmlEach
    xmlEach = {
        key, val ->
            out << {
                "${key}"(val.attr) {
                    val.nodes.each(xmlEach)
                }
            }
    }
    struc.nodes.each(xmlEachClosure)
}

println builder.bind(xml)
```

As output you get XML simliar to the following:

```
<ROOT>
    <folder1 id='1' path='ROOT/folder1' name='folder1' isFolder='true'>
        <folder1.1 id='2' path='ROOT/folder1/folder1.1' name='folder1.1' isFolder='true'>
            <folder1.1.1 id='3' path='ROOT/folder1/folder1.1/folder1.1.1' name='folder1.1.1' isFolder='true'></folder1.1.1>
        </folder1.1>
    </folder1>
...
</ROOT>
```

Comment: anyone trying this in Jenkins pipeline script should be aware of [JENKINS-32766](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32766)